# Partial string search in C++

Tags: c++

Let's say I have a vector of strings called `info` that reads names of websites from a file one by one sequentially.

This is what I have that searches for names, by the complete name only:

```
int linearSearch(vector <string> inputs, string search_key){
    for (int x=0; x<inputs.size(); x++){

        if (search_key==inputs[x]){

            return x;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Now what if I wanted to COUNT the amount of websites with a particular word in it?

So if I had

1. apple.com
2. mac.com
3. macapple.com
4. applepie.com
5. potato.com

and I searched for "apple", it would return 3.

Comment: Oh sorry, I want to know how I can modify this to count a file not by a perfect match, but by a partial match. Ie counting the amount of websites that has a phrase such as "apple" in it,

Answer (score 1):

You can use `string::find` to perform a partial search of the string and store the value into a `size_t` variable.

Compare that to `std::string::npos` and increment count if they are not equal.

Here is an simple example using arrays not vector so you can learn and make modifications as required.

```
int main() {

    string inputs[2] = {"stack overflow", "stack exchange"};
    string search_key = "stack";
    int count;

    for(int i = 0; i <sizeof(inputs)/sizeof(inputs[0]); i++)
    {
        //npos returns -1. If substring is not found, find will return -1.
        //if substring is found, condition fails and count is incremented 
        if (inputs[i].find(search_key) != string::npos)
            count++;
    }

    cout << count;

    return 0;
}
```

[Here](https://ideone.com/EiqeCA) is the link for the code above. You can see that the output is 2 as expected as the word `stack` occurs twice in the `inputs` array.